# Mirrors produce spurious indentation under mma-mode

Tags: yasnippet

**NB**:  This problem seems to be limited to [mma-mode](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/skaslev/emacs.d/master/progmodes/mma.el) (for Mathematica).

For example, suppose I define a snippet like this:

```
# key: test
# name: test
# --
$1
$1
```

Then, I test it (with `C-c C-t`).  After I type the first character (`x`), my terminal looks like this (the `▮` indicates the position of the cursor).

```
x▮
  x
```

Note that a couple of spurious spaces were added in front of the mirrored `x`.

This behavior continues with every additional keystroke, as long as mirroring is taking place:

```
xy▮
    xy
```

It happens even if the keystroke is for a backspace:

```
x▮
      x
```

---

As I said at the beginning, I see this problem only with mma-mode.

Now, mma-mode is not maintained, AFAICT.  Therefore, the most I can hope for is some workaround.

---

Any ideas on how I could prevent the addition of spurious spaces before mirrors?

Comment: Does setting `yas-indent-line` to `fixed` help? If you have those 2 lines in a `.m` file, does `M-x indent-according-to-mode` on the second line also cause indentation?

Comment: @npostavs: `indent-according-to-mode` does give a clue: if I run it on an empty buffer under `mma-mode`, two spaces get inserted.  Unfortunately, however, if I add the line `# expand-env: ((yas-indent-line 'fixed))` to the snippet's header, I still get the behavior I showed before.

Comment: What yasnippet version are you using? I think older versions wouldn't apply `expand-env` at the right time (see https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet/pull/743). Setting `yas-indent-line` in `mma-mode-hook` should be okay.

Comment: Actually [these comments near the top of mma-mode.el](https://github.com/skaslev/emacs.d/blob/master/progmodes/mma.el#L47-L48) give a hint, "If point is not on the leading whitespace of the current line, indents by steps of \`mma-indentation'" - yasnippet calls the indent function with point sitting just *after* the leading whitespace. Perhaps replacing `(back-to-indentation)` with `(beginning-of-line)` in `yas--indent-region` would help.

Comment: @npostavs: Thanks for your suggestions.  I'm using version 0.11.0 of yasnippet.  In any case, setting `yas-indent-line` in `mma-mode-hook` did not help.  I don't entirely understand you last suggestion.  Do you mean that I should redefine `yas--indent-region`?  If so, is there a way to do this "buffer-locally", for `mma-mode` buffers only?

Comment: My last suggestion was more for myself to consider changing yasnippet, but I've just downloaded `mma.el` and it seems that calling the indent function at the beginning of line has a different but equally weird behaviour, so yasnippet's auto indent should just be disabled. Yasnippet version 0.11 indeed needs a bit of help to make this work, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mma-mode` seems to have a strange (non-idempotent) indentation function.  Therefore you should stop yasnippet from trying to use it when in `mma-mode`:

```el
(defun my-mma-mode-hook ()
  (setq-local yas-indent-line 'fixed))
(add-hook 'mma-mode-hook #'my-mma-mode-hook)
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work in yasnippet versions 0.11 and earlier because it doesn't respect `yas-indent-line` for mirror updates.  This will be fixed in the upcoming 0.12, but you can use this advice to fix it in the meantime:

```el
;; NOTE: this also disables `$>' indent markers in snippets,
;; but hardly anyone uses those anyway.
(defun yas-indent-line-is-auto-p (&rest _)
  (eq yas-indent-line 'auto))
(advice-add 'yas--indent-region :before-while #'yas-indent-line-is-auto-p)
```